# How to find indicies of longest run of consecutive values in ordered list?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, artificial-intelligence

I'm building an AI player for a yahtzee game and what I'm trying to do at the moment is have it evaluate the 5 dice given to it (in a sorted ArrayList), to decide the probability of attaining a low/high straight from the current position (e.g. with 1 or 2 more rolls); and which dice to hold as a result. At the moment I acheive the probability by finding the longest streak of consecutive numbers and calculating probabilities from there. What I'm having issues with is telling the computer which dice to hold. Basically I can't find the start and end of the streak.

My method for getting the longest streak is like this:

```
public Class checkStraight{

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> dieFreq = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();    
    private ArrayList<Die> dice = new ArrayList<Die>(); //Die has a method "getValue()" 
    // which returns the face value and a method roll() which assigns a random value.

    public checkStraight(){
        for(Die d : dice){ 
            d.roll();    
        } 
        for(int i = 1; i<7; i++){
            dieFreq.put(i, 0);
        }
        buildMap();
    }    

    public void buildMap(){
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){   
            dieFreq.put(dice.get(i).getValue(), dieFreq.get(dice.get(i).getValue()) + 1); 
        }
    }

    public int longestStreak(){
        int count = 1;
        int highCount = 1;   
        for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
            if(dieFreq.get(i) != 0 && dieFreq.get(i+1) != 0){ 
                count++;
            }
            else{
                if(count>highCount){
                    highCount = count;
                }
            count = 1;
        }
        return highCount;
    }
}
```

Obviously if you're going for a straight you should hold one of each consecutive die and reroll the others, but I can't see a way to find which dice comprise the longest streak in the ArrayList of Die due to potentially having more than one die of the same value.
I want to pass integers into a new ArrayList to determine which dice to hold (1 for hold 0 for reroll). Can any of you think of a way I can do that, either within the method for calculating the longest streak or some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have these bugs in your `longestStreak()` method

1) counts should start at (and be reset to)  zero, not one.

2) your loop does not include 6

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++) {
```

should be

```
for(int i=1; i<=6; i++) {
```

Strategically, even a correct longest streak method will not help you with the problem you are trying to solve, because 1, 2, 4, 5 yields a 33% chance per reroll of getting a straight, while the longest streak is only two.